# PHP - Error al recibir data por $_POST desde WebHook

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de recibir data desde el WebHook de CuentaDigital.com, pero a la hora de hacer la prueba que te hace el servidor de ellos siempre me sale `error 403`. La información que otorgan es escasa o nula, lo único que me respondieron fue

> "Su funcionamiento esta normalizado como todos los webhooks, no envia
>   variables por lo que si esperas un http post con variables no
>   recibiras nada lo que estas buscando es
>   `$csv=file_get_contents('php://input');`"

Ahora, yo coloco el `file_get_contents('php://input')` pero sin embargo me sigue dando `error 403`, por ende no puedo recibir ninguna información

Comment: 403 = Prohibido. No estas autorizado para acceder a ello.

Comment: Si, pero porque el error? no encuentro razón alguna, solo sucede si se le envía un POST, porque se puede acceder normalmente si abris por http

Comment: Por HTTP es GET. Puede que este habilitado para GET pero no paara POST

Comment: has probado la utilización de curl? te puedo explicar un poco para ver si te sirve..

Comment: No he probado, si me podes pasara un ejemplo, bienvenido será!

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto, el problema era el Hosting que me bloqueaba un HTTP POST, probé el Script en un VPS y funcinó normal. Este es el Script

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    // fetch RAW input
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

    // decode json
    $object = json_enc($json);

    file_put_contents('callback.test.txt', print_r($object, true));
}
?>
```